# How can I compile OpenFoam with a custom MPI implementation?

Tags: compiler-errors, mpi, openfoam

I am trying to install OpenFoam-19.06 in a CentOS 6.6
I have a MPI version in `/global/mpi/mympich`.
In the file `etc/bashrc` I've created the variable:

```
export WM_MPLIB=MYMPICH
```

>
and in the file `etc/config.sh/mpi` I've created a new case:

```
MYMPICH)
    export FOAM_MPI=mympich
    export MPI_ARCH_PATH=/global/mpi/mympich
    export MPICH_PATH=$MPI_ARCH_PATH

    _foamAddPath    $MPI_ARCH_PATH/bin
    _foamAddLib     $MPI_ARCH_PATH/lib
    ;;
```

Then I set the environment variables with:

> source etc/bashrc

and compile the third party software with (in the appropriate directory):

> ./makeCGAL

Finally, I compile OpenFoam with (in the appropriate directory):

> ./Allwmake

It seems to start well:

```
========================================
2019-11-15 13:24:03 +0100
Starting compile OpenFOAM-v1906 Allwmake
  Gcc system compiler
  linux64GccDPInt32Opt, with MYMPICH mympich
========================================

built wmake-bin (linux64Gcc)

========================================
Start ThirdParty Allwmake
========================================
using:  gcc -m64 -DOPENFOAM=1906 -DWM_DP -DWM_LABEL_SIZE=32 -Wall -O3 -fPIC
using:  g++ -std=c++11 -m64 -DOPENFOAM=1906 -DWM_DP -DWM_LABEL_SIZE=32 -Wall -Wextra -Wold-style-cast -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-invalid-offsetof -Wno-attributes -Wno-unknown-pragmas -O3 -DNoRepository -ftemplate-depth-100 -fPIC

========================================
Build MPI libraries if required
    /global/mpi/mympich
```

But it ends With the following result:

```
module.h:236:37: warning: ‘foldval’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
 #define SCOTCH_NAME_PREFIX_INTERN   _SCOTCH
                                     ^
vdgraph_separate_ml.c:90:23: note: ‘foldval’ was declared here
   int                 foldval;
                       ^
cp: cannot stat `../bin/[agm]*': No such file or directory
make: [install] Error 1 (ignored)
cp: cannot stat `../bin/d[agm]*': No such file or directory
make: [install] Error 1 (ignored)
cp: cannot stat `../include/*esmumps*.h': No such file or directory
make: [install] Error 1 (ignored)
cp: cannot stat `../lib/*esmumps*.so': No such file or directory
make: [install] Error 1 (ignored)
    ln: OpenFOAM/lnInclude
    ln: OSspecific/POSIX/lnInclude
    ln: ./lnInclude
In file included from PstreamGlobals.C:28:0:
PstreamGlobals.H:42:17: fatal error: mpi.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [/home/OpenFOAM-v1906/build/linux64GccDPInt32OptMYMPICH/src/Pstream/mpi/PstreamGlobals.o] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
In file included from UPstream.C:32:0:
PstreamGlobals.H:42:17: fatal error: mpi.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [/home/OpenFOAM-v1906/build/linux64GccDPInt32OptMYMPICH/src/Pstream/mpi/UPstream.o] Error 1
In file included from UOPwrite.C:34:0:
PstreamGlobals.H:42:17: fatal error: mpi.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
In file included from UIPread.C:34:0:
PstreamGlobals.H:42:17: fatal error: mpi.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

So far, I haven't found a good guide to do what I'm targeting.

Comment: Is it possible for you add the full compilation log as an attachment? Also, could you please revisit Build guide in OpenFOAM **gitlab wiki** (i will add the address if I can have an access through my PC). Have you set the configurations in $FOAM/etc/config.sh/* files?

Answer (score 1):

In OpenFOAM-1712 and later, there is provision for just what you want. It's called `USERMPI`. If you specify this, it will look for a corresponding mplib rule, which you also are in charge of creating.

Probably best to raise as a documentation issue/query on their gitlab tracker.

If you want to see a really detailed example, take a look at the spack openfoam/package.py - there it is populated by values from spack

Answer (score -2):

no, I think you have installed mpich? or something else. We don't have a mpi named "mympi".

Comment: I am pretty sure this is meant to be an answer. But that is not very obvious. Please [edit] to rephrase. Ideally without asking a question, even if rhetoric.